# FileNotFoundException for URL.readText in androidTest

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing

In an Android app, when I use a Kotlin class from a unit test, mocking out `android.util.Base64` the test is successful. Running the test as an androidTest it fails when:

```
URL(urlRequestToken).readText()
```

throws `FileNotFoundException` for an `https` url. The manifest has the network permission (when it didn't the error was different). Copy/pasting `urlRequestToken` into the browser gives an expected result but loading it with `URL` from the phone in the test always throws `FileNotFoundException`.

The test includes a network check with `ConnectivityManager` which is successful so there is network.

Is there something else I need to be doing to get it to access the url from the test?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `FileNotFoundException` is completely wrong and has nothing to do with a file not being found. The unit test works as it mocks `android.util.Base64` using `java.util.Base64`. The difference is `android.util.Base64` by default uses wrapping which adds a `\n` at the end of the encoded string which breaks the Flickr signature. The real error is HTTP 401 as the signature is invalid but `URL.readText` reports it as `FileNotFoundException`.

The solution in Android is to use:

```
Base64.encodeToString(hmac.doFinal(baseString.toByteArray()), Base64.NO_WRAP)
```